# Escape double back-slash

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I need to match all strings like `/(\:\w+)/` (eg. `:hello`), except if it is escaped with back-slash on first character, like it: `\:hello`. So, in this case, will not match. But, if I double escape it, I can ignore the back-slash of sentence, and will work normally, like: `\\:hello` will receive `:hello` only. And so on.

**Examples**:

- `test :hello test` will match `:hello`
- `test \:hello test` will not match
- `test \\:hello test` will match `:hello`
- `test \\\:hello test` will not match
- `test \\\\:hello test` will match `:hello`
- `test \\\\\:hello test` will not match
- `test \\\\\\:hello test` will match `:hello`

Comment: Use negative lookbehind.

Comment: @Barmar: Can't use (only) lookbehind, lookbehind assertions must have fixed length. I'd use lookbehind to check that previous character is not a backslash, then match the whole thing with normal expression, using a capture for the string itself. Can't figure out a way to match only `:hello` for the full match.

Comment: Then he may have to (shudder) write some **code** to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses `\K` (*discards previously matched characters*).

```
(?:\s|^)(?:\\\\)*\K:\w+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oJ7oI8/2)

Comment: Thanks! The `\K` solve everything (or at least for this problem)! I did some updates and work well too: http://regex101.com/r/aL6hX3/2

Comment: yep, `{0,}` would be written as `*` And don't remove the `^` anchor , if you do that, then it won't match the `:hello` which is present in the first line. See http://regex101.com/r/aL6hX3/3

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$regex = '/(?<=^|[^\\\\])(?:[\\\\]{2})*(?P<tag>:\w+)/';
```

And some tests:

```
$tests = array(
    'test :hello test',
    'test \\:hello test',
    'test \\\\:hello test',
    'test \\\\\\:hello test',
    'test \\\\\\\\:hello test',
    'test \\\\\\\\\\:hello test',
    'test \\\\\\\\\\\\:hello test',
);
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match($regex, $test, $match);
    if (empty($match)) {
        echo 'NOPE:  ', $test, "\n";
    } else {
        echo 'MATCH: ', $test, ' - ', $match['tag'], "\n";
    }
}
```

It gives me:

```
MATCH: test :hello test - :hello
NOPE:  test \:hello test
MATCH: test \\:hello test - :hello
NOPE:  test \\\:hello test
MATCH: test \\\\:hello test - :hello
NOPE:  test \\\\\:hello test
MATCH: test \\\\\\:hello test - :hello
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

if occurs at the begining of the line

```
^(?:\\\\)*(:hello)
```

anywhere else

```
\s(?:\\\\)*(:hello)\b
```

the back reference `\1` will contain `:hello`

see the example

http://regex101.com/r/hF1mW6/1

Comment: This only works if the string is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Barmar will remove the anchor so that it will match anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like [this](http://regex101.com):-

```
(?!<=)(:hello)
```

Comment: But you want to extract :hello??So if yes then it is extracting the same.

Comment: I want extract `:hello`, except if it is escaped like `\:hello`. Except-except if it is double-escaped like `\\:hello`. And so on.